# Database logic advice

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-deadlocks, database-optimization

I've been working on optimizing a database. The main idea with this database is that there is people populating it (several times during the day) and in parallel we have our own business people consulting it constantly and generating big reports of the data on it. I'm looking for suggestions on how should I need to structure it in order to don't make a mess on tables deadlocks because of selects or because of the amount of operations that I will be doing on it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you read about MySQL InnoDB MVCC and its SQL isolation levels? (Also MySQL explicit locking. Also wiki concurrency_control & serializability.) MVCC has the benefit that readers do not hold back writers. But blah entire books blah too broad blah. DItto "any thoughts".

Comment: How is this task progressing?

Comment: @RickJames Poorly. Where I currently work they don't believe in managing my tasks as a dev, so this is at the bottom of a lot of stuff to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Warehousing?

[*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) speeds up "big reports", often 10-fold.

Perhaps you also need some [*High speed ingestion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) tips?  This deals with multiple writers pounding on a single 'Fact' table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't optimize for both OLTP and OLAP. Strategically the best solution is to extract your data from the transactional system into a data warehouse and data marts (star schema/dimensional models) for reporting and business intelligence.